# Searching Array for Different values to match user input

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have been learning javascript for two months now and I'm doing some precourse work and got stuck on this question. I know I need a for a loop. but I am completely lost and there doesn't seem to be a comparable problem anywhere to learn from. the problem is://Given a string, write a program that counts how many colors are used in that string. For the purposes of our challenge, let's say all the available colors are: blue, green, gray, red, black, and purple.

So here is the code I have so far

```
//declaring values and user input
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];
const sillySentence = prompt("Tell me a colorful Rhyme: ");

//for loop to solve the problem



//start output
console.log("You Listed " + x + " colors in your rhyme.")
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { // body of your loop }`

Comment: is a very simple filter using `Array#filter()`  and `String#indexOf()` or `String#includes()` all of which are easy to research by themselves

Comment: colors.filter(color => sillySentence.indexOf(color) !== -1).length

Answer (score 1):

If a for loop is not a necessary requirement, here you have a different approach without one. If elements of color array have only letters you could use [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that returns an array of matches, to build the regex we convert the colors array into string and replace the `,` for `|` that means **or** in a regex so the result is something like **/blue|green|gray/**, then we count the length of the matches:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];

const sillySentence = prompt("Text: ");

var r = new RegExp(colors.toString().replace(/,/g, "|"), "g");

var found = (sillySentence.match(r) > 0) ? sillySentence.match(r).length : 0;

console.log(found);
```

This example won't work if we have `,` in the strings of colors.

Comment: This is probably the smartest answer right now. Please explain how match works. He is new to JS. Also, he need a forloop...even tho this is the smartest answer it's not a valid one

Comment: @TamoDev not for everyone : / , I've added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using regular expressions. This code will only accept colors as words, e.g. `bluegreen` will not match anything.

**Edit**: now takes into account unique colors only.

```js
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'gray', 'red', 'black', 'purple'];
const sillySentence = prompt('Tell me a colorful Rhyme:');

const result = (sillySentence.match(
  new RegExp('(\\b' + colors.join('|') + '\\b)', 'g'))
    .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
  || []).length;

console.log(result);
```

**Explanation**:

- This builds a regexp of the form `/\b(blue|green|red)\b/`, which basically says: a word among blue, green and red (`\b` is the word boundary character, preventing `thisisthebluecolor` from matching `blue`).
- It uses [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to build that regexp.
- It uses
  [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
  to test the input string against that regexp.
- It uses [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove duplicates (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/965834))
- the `|| []` basically says: if the regexp doesn't match, consider the result of `String.match` an empty array (so that `.length`, the size of that result, will return 0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];
var sillySentence = prompt("Tell me a colorful Rhyme: ");
let x = 0;
if (sillySentence) {
    sillySentence = sillySentence.toLowerCase();
    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        if (sillySentence.indexOf(colors[i]) >= 0) {
            x += 1;
        }
    }
}

//start output
console.log("You Listed " + x + " colors in your rhyme.");
```

It'll be best to loop through number of colors as they will be less than number of words of the rhyme and it will count unique colors only.

Comment: This code is not working completely. it doesn't pass a the test case with multiple color words ex. red blue, return one instead of 2

Comment: awesome.  i tried to use .length but i messed it up somewhere and already deleted it from frustration. thanks guy!

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Solution

A Simple, but inefficient, solution is:

- Lowercase the string
- Split the string by spaces and punctuation.

Then you iterate through the words and try to find the colors. Example:

```
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];
const sillySentence = prompt("Tell me a colorful Rhyme: ");

const colorCount = new Set();

const words = sillySentence.toLowerCase().split(/[\s,.:;]+/);
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  const word = words[i];
  if (colors.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
    colorCount.add(word);
  }
}

console.log(colorCount.size);
```

### Efficient Solution

A more efficient solution is to populate a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and use it to quickly lookup the colors:

```
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];
const sillySentence = prompt("Tell me a colorful Rhyme: ");

const colorSet = new Set();
colors.forEach(color => colorSet.add(color));

const colorCount = new Set();

const words = sillySentence.toLowerCase().split(/[\s,.:;]+/);
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  const word = words[i];
  if (colorSet.has(word)) {    
    colorCount.add(word);
  }
}

console.log(colorCount.size);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't pass all the test cases. Try blue red blue black and returns 2, instead of 3

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a correct answer because you are asking for a **forloop** I wanted to share another way to do things in JS since you are new into JS.

```
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];
const sillySentence = prompt("Tell me a colorful Rhyme: ");

    let count = 0;
    sillySentence.split(' ').find((color)=> {
      if (colors.includes(color) !== -1) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    console.log("You Listed " + count + " colors in your rhyme.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could just use `regular expression` group match (`/(blue)/` for example) and simply count the length ... this way you do not have to worry about special characters, splitting to words etc.

Here is an example:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];
const rhyme = "I love blue, and red, but mostly blue!! and sometimes green! and red... NO gray!"

console.log(colors.reduce((r,c) => {
   let matches = rhyme.match(new RegExp(`(${c})`, 'gi'))
   return matches ? Object.assign(r, { [c]: matches.length }) : r
},{}))
```

**Note**: I wraped the whole thing in a `reduce` just so I can return an object with the counts etc but I am sure you get the picture.

Answer (score -1):

Get the value of the prompt and split it into an array, then iterate that array and for each value in that array see if there exist a same element in colors array, if it is so then increase value of x by 1

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "gray", "red", "black", "purple"];
const sillySentence = prompt("Tell me a colorful Rhyme: ");

let x = 0;
sillySentence.split(' ').forEach(function(item) {
  if (colors.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    x += 1;
  }
});
console.log("You Listed " + x + " colors in your rhyme.")
```

Note: This program is not taking care of unique color in the prompt value. For example if any color appears twice , it will consider it as 2

Comment: This code doesn't work. It also doesn't count if you put more than one color

Comment: @TamoDev which part does not work? Share that scenario

Comment: nvm it works! Idk how gave you the -1 tho.. but this answer works pretty solid. Good job!